# Remove \x-escaped sequences from a string

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a hex string and I need to compare the string by checking if '\' is in value and then do and do encode operation

```
value='\x1a\x01'


(Pdb) value.encode("hex")
'1a01'
```

However when i check like this its returning false

```
(Pdb) '\\' in value
False
```

Comment: The '\' in `\x1a` is a visual representation, it isn't "in" the string.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I like to do encoding for the hex strings which has '\x' and leave the other strings

Comment: Is your data all of the for '\xnn\xnn\xnn'?  If not, can you show an example?

Comment: value='\x1a\x01' >>> value.encode("hex")
'1a01'

Comment: new_value='installed'>>> new_value.encode("hex")
'696e7374616c6c6564'

Comment: `>>> 'inst\x1a\x01alled'.encode('hex')
'696e73741a01616c6c6564'` - the x-escaped sequences are encoded, so why do you need to identify them?  Where are your inputs coming from, and why do you need to encode the x-escaped sequences?  This smells like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: the input is decoded value which has normal string as well as \x strings,Now i need to encode only \x strings

Comment: @snakecharmerb: FYI [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53722358/2564301) is the Y part of this question. (Sanity warning: the random attempts shown there may cause brain damage or other health issues.)

Comment: @usr2564301 I had been trying these options from what i saw from other posts in stackoverflow and I was not aware \x is a visual representation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode the x-escaped sequences using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

First of all, define a regular expression that will capture these sequences.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\\x[0-9a-fA-f]{2}')  # matches \x and two-digit hex value
```

Note that `\x` needs to be escaped so that the re compiler doesn't reject it as a bogus regex escape sequence.

Now define a function that will encode the matched sequences.

```
def enc(match):
    return match.group(0).decode('string-escape').encode('hex')
```

When encoding, we need to decode from 'string-escape' first because we need to escape the input string so that the `\x..` sequences get matched.

Now perform the substitution on a string-escaped version of the input string, remembering to decode the output afterwards (otherwise sequences like `\n` will be escaped):

```
s = 'abc\x1a\x01def'
escaped = re.sub(pattern, enc, s.encode('string-escape'))
result = escaped.decode('string-escape')
print result
abc1a01def
```

Comment: @Awin: but in Python **there is no `\x22` in a string**. There isn't, there never has been. It is a notation only. You are asking something similar to "`val = 0x10`, how do I remove `0x`?" -- the same answer. It is a notational thing **only**.

Comment: >>> a='\x22'
>>> a.encode("hex")
'22'
This is what im expecting

Comment: @Awin `print '\x22'` -> `"`.  `\x22` can be represented as a character in ascii/uf-8 so Python will not represent it as a byte sequence.  `\x1a\x01` are not representable as characters, hence Python displays them in your strings.